# Rails params attributes - using the params fields in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following **strong params** in my **developers_controller** named `location_params`

```
  def location_params
    params.require(:location).permit(:country, {:ads_attributes => [:remote, :days]})
  end
```

When I set a debug breakpoint in the code, to test on how to use the fields :remote and :days, I have to use the following code to get **:remote** and **:days** in the **console**.

```
location_params[:ads_attributes]["2"][:remote]
```

I do not understand and know how to remove this `["2"]` index. I would like to select the `params` with the following code `location_params[:ads_attributes][:remote]`

This is the result in the console from `location_params[:ads_attributes]`

```
<ActionController::Parameters 
{"0"=><ActionController::Parameters {} permitted: true>, 
"1"=><ActionController::Parameters {"days"=>"12"} permitted: true>,
"2"=><ActionController::Parameters {"remote"=>"1"} permitted: true>}
permitted: true>
```

I did make a search on stackoverflow and I could not find a solution to this specific issue with the index.

- [Rails: Access params of a form with a nested model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002087/rails-access-params-of-a-form-with-a-nested-model)
- [Strong Params, Nested Attributes and Mongoid don't seem to work because of *_attributes suffix in form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527708/strong-params-nested-attributes-and-mongoid-dont-seem-to-work-because-of-att)
- [Ruby/Rails - Accessing params values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420393/ruby-rails-accessing-params-values)
- [Strong Params, Nested Attributes and Mongoid don't seem to work because of *_attributes suffix in form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527708/strong-params-nested-attributes-and-mongoid-dont-seem-to-work-because-of-att)

Comment: The problem is in your form. That's how it sends data. If you want params to have another shape, change the form.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomment better to fix form view, which add these numbers in here:

```
<%= link_to_add_association "Add another", f, :ads %>
<%= f.fields_for :ads do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.form_group ::remote do |ad| %>
          <%= ad.label :remote %> *
          <%= ad.text_field :remote %>
      <% end %>
      <%= ff.form_group :days do |ad| %>
          <%= ad.label :days %> *
          <%= ad.text_field :days %>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to_remove_association "remove", ff %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help